# PHP Redirecting users to the page they left once logged in

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

Looking to redirect the user of my site to the page they were trying to access when they have logged in. I am using a function to protect my pages until the user has logged in, if a user tries to access a secure page they are redirected to a "continue" page to sign in. I am trying to make it so that once the user has logged in, they will go straight back to the page they were trying to look at? Is this possible?

```
function protect_page() {
if (logged_in() === false) {
header('Location: continue.php');
exit();
}
}
```

Comment: store page in session.

Comment: Why not send the current page using post or get method?

Comment: I know a lot of sites store the previous URL the client was at in a GET variable. Such as `/login.php?back=home.php`

Comment: How would I code any of these? Not too good with PHP still learning?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very frequently asked question with lots of answers. For example

[Redirecting to previous page after login? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523468/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-login-php)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a query string for the current page they are on. For example if they attempt to access a page **profile** which they need to be logged in for I would do:

`header('Location: continue.php?goto=profile'); exit;`

Comment: Although how would this know which page the user was on before they logged in?