# How to go back to previous page after successful login

Tags: php

I am working with a login system. Here is my code to redirect some other page after successful login. I just want to go back to the previous page instead of redirect some specific page.

Code: login.php

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($fgmembersite->Login())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: then you'll need to save (in $_SESSION maybe) where the user was before he was redirected to login

Comment: you can use `HTTP_REFERER` but you must check the url from it.

Comment: this ansewer will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523468/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-login-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the previous page**
add these:

```
session_start();
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

**login page**

```
    session_start();

    require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        if($fgmembersite->Login())
        {
            $redirect_url = (isset($_SESSION['redirect_url'])) ? $_SESSION['redirect_url'] : '/';
            unset($_SESSION['redirect_url']);
            header("Location: $redirect_url", true, 303);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have this in previous page       `<?php require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");


if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit; 
}

?>
`

Comment: @sanzuu Edited answer to include your previous page details.

Comment: This code is working `<?php require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
 if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) 
 { $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; header('Location: login.php'); exit; } ?>` but your edited code some different , which one is correct?

Comment: I think you are missing some bracket in line no. 3 .

Comment: Yeah I missed a ( for the if statement. Fixed it.

Comment: WOW!! its working outstanding . I accept it as a helpful answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:
In your login page:
$comingFrom = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{

    //or you can store it in session also.so that you can redirect it from anywhere.
    if($fgmembersite->Login())
    {
       $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL($comingFrom);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **PHP** you can get the previous page using `$_SERVER` variable. By this `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, which contains the page URL from the current page is being called.

> But sometimes there is an option in the browser which some users can
>   disable  to send this information.

So beware to use this option.

Alternate to this option is to set a value in form and send it along with other data, that is still vulnerable as this can be changed by user easily.

Comment: Valuable tips! I remember.